# How can i find the train error with 70: 30 split on the data?

Tags: scikit-learn

`X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)`
This is how i split the data.
I try to check about overfitting or underfitting so i want to compare the train_error to the test_error.

I calculate the test_error with `metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test,Y_pred)`
How could i find the train error? Is there a way using sklearn?

I tried to `metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_train,Y_pred)` i have a bug because the sets have different size, which i do understand.

Comment: Why you dont predict your train values and compare them to their right label?

Comment: You don't have a bug, you have an expected error: you cannot  use the same `Y_pred` in both cases - what exactly would you comparing in such a case? You should first `predict` your train set, and then calculate the MSE using these predictions and `Y_train`.